# How to wrap flexbox over multiple rows and columns?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to build a gallery in form of a masonry, but I can't get my head around wrapping of flexboxes?

[image]

I got a simple UL list and I've added the style needed, but things are not floating and wrapping as it should.

```css
.masonry {

  margin: 48px -2px;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
}

.masonry li {
 
  height: 300px;
  flex-basis: calc(33.33% - 4px);
  margin: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  
  background-color: #C9F4FF;
}

.masonry li:nth-child(1), .masonry li:nth-child(7) {

  height: 604px;
  
  background-color: #FFB4FF;
}

.masonry li:nth-child(4), .masonry li:nth-child(4) {

  flex-basis: calc(66.66% - 4px);
  background-color: #B9EDA8;
}
```

```html
<!-- masonry starts -->
    <ul class="masonry">
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
        <li>&nbsp;</li>
    </ul>
<!-- masonry ends -->
```

The result looks like this, which is kinda funny :)

[image]

Maybe someone knows how to write the correct CSS to make things wrap correctly?

Comment: What you want to achieve is can be done using CSS grid.

Comment: Flexbox feels a bit safer, as it has been supported in all major browsers for a while now.

Comment: Both CSS grid and Flexbox supports IE11 you can check this link to see the browser compatibility [https://caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flexbox can't do that with its own layout capabilities, it needs some help, so here is a CSS solution that assume the size of the items is given.

The main trick here is to add an extra element inside the `li` and make that the "styled" one, and use the `li` for the main layout.

The "light green" items gets a left/right margin, to push them accordingly, and with that make space for the "light purple".

Since a flex item (here the `li`) can't dynamically grow both vertical and horizontal, we instead use its inner `div` to take twice the height, and with that enable the requested layout.

This setup, combined with Flexbox's `order` property,  will now make it very simply to adjust its layout using e.g. media query for a portrait layout (vertically stacked) etc.

---

Note, to make this all dynamically sized by its content, either a script or CSS Grid will be needed.

Here is a great post shedding some light (and more solutions) on *Masonry*:

- [CSS-only masonry layout but with elements ordered horizontally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44377343/css-only-masonry-layout-but-with-elements-ordered-horizontally/45200955#45200955)

---

Stack snippet

```css
.masonry {
  margin: 48px -2px;
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style: none;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  display: flex;
}

.masonry li {
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 3);
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
}

.masonry li div {
  display: relative;
  flex: 1;
  margin: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  background-color: #C9F4FF;
}

.masonry li:nth-child(1) div,
.masonry li:nth-child(7) div {
  display: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(200% - 4px);              /*  twice the height  */
  background-color: #FFB4FF;
}

.masonry li:nth-child(4),
.masonry li:nth-child(8) {
  flex-basis: 100%;                      /*  100% width to force wrap  */
}

.masonry li:nth-child(4) div,
.masonry li:nth-child(8) div {
  background-color: #B9EDA8;
}

.masonry li:nth-child(4) div {
  margin-left: calc((100% / 3) + 2px);   /*  pushed to left  */
}

.masonry li:nth-child(8) div {
  margin-right: calc((100% / 3) + 2px);  /*  pushed to right  */
}
```

```html
<!-- masonry starts -->
<ul class="masonry">
    <li><div>&nbsp;</div></li>
    <li><div>&nbsp;</div></li>
    <li><div>&nbsp;</div></li>
    <li><div>&nbsp;</div></li>
    <li><div>&nbsp;</div></li>
    <li><div>&nbsp;</div></li>
    <li><div>&nbsp;</div></li>
    <li><div>&nbsp;</div></li>
</ul>
<!-- masonry ends -->
```

Comment: Nice, this looks promising, I'll give it a try.

Answer (score 4):

I've created a quick image gallery from the help I got and have to say it was as simple and neat as I wanted it.

[image]

```css
body {
    
    padding: 48px;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.masonry {
    margin: -2px;
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style: none;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    display: flex
}

.masonry li {
    flex-basis: calc(100% / 3);
    position: relative;
    height: 300px;
    display: flex
}

@media (max-width: 1199.98px) {
    .masonry li {
        height: 250px
    }
}

@media (max-width: 991.98px) {
    .masonry li {
        height: 200px
    }
}

@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
    .masonry li {
        flex-basis: calc(100% / 2) !important;
        height: 160px !important
    }
}

.masonry li:nth-child(1) a, .masonry li:nth-child(7) a {
    width: calc(100% - 2px);
    height: calc(200% - 2px);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0
}

.masonry li:nth-child(4), .masonry li:nth-child(8) {
    flex-basis: 100%
}

.masonry li:nth-child(4) a {
    margin-left: calc((100% / 3) + 1px)
}

.masonry li:nth-child(8) a {
    margin-right: calc((100% / 3) + 1px)
}

.masonry a {
    margin: 1px;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    position: relative;
    color: #fff;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1
}

@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
    .masonry a {
        width: auto !important;
        height: auto !important;
        margin: 1px !important;
        position: relative !important
    }
}

.masonry a:hover {
    text-decoration: none
}

.masonry a:hover img {
    transform: scale(1.04);
    opacity: 1
}

.masonry img {
    transition: opacity .2s, transform .3s;
    opacity: .5
}

.masonry-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #000;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0
}

.masonry-caption {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 0;
    padding: 24px;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    position: relative;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: flex;
    z-index: 2
}

@media (max-width: 575.98px) {
    .masonry-caption {
        padding: 0
    }
}

.masonry-caption:hover strong, .masonry-caption:hover span {
    transition: background-color .4s ease-in-out;
    background-color: #000
}

.masonry-caption strong, .masonry-caption span {
    padding: 4px 8px;
    transition: background-color .15s ease-in-out
}

.masonry-caption strong {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    font-family: "opensans-semibold";
    font-size: 1.625rem
}

@media (max-width: 991.98px) {
    .masonry-caption strong {
        font-size: 1.4rem
    }
}

@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
    .masonry-caption strong {
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 1.1rem;
        background-color: transparent !important
    }
}

@media (max-width: 991.98px) {
    .masonry-caption span {
        font-size: .938rem
    }
}

@media (max-width: 767.98px) {
    .masonry-caption span {
        font-size: .875rem;
        background-color: transparent !important
    }
}

.cover {

    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: inherit;
    object-position: 50% 50%;
    object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<!-- masonry starts -->
    <ul class="masonry">
        <li>
            <a href="" class="masonry-holder" title="">
                <div class="masonry-caption"><strong>Image title</strong><span>label</span></div>
                <div class="masonry-image"><img src="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5594/15041847508_8e9ef380f9_z.jpg" rel="noindex" class="cover" width="360" height="240" alt=""></div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="" class="masonry-holder" title="">
                <div class="masonry-caption"><strong>Image title</strong><span>label</span></div>
                <div class="masonry-image"><img src="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5559/15225339791_f01c6697b6_z.jpg" rel="noindex" class="cover" width="360" height="240" alt=""></div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="" class="masonry-holder" title="">
                <div class="masonry-caption"><strong>Image title</strong><span>label</span></div>
                <div class="masonry-image"><img src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3914/15041657969_ac472610cb_z.jpg" rel="noindex" class="cover" width="360" height="240" alt=""></div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="" class="masonry-holder" title="">
                <div class="masonry-caption"><strong>Image title</strong><span>label</span></div>
                <div class="masonry-image"><img src="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5564/15041850517_00f9b6667f_z.jpg" rel="noindex" class="cover" width="360" height="240" alt=""></div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="" class="masonry-holder" title="">
                <div class="masonry-caption"><strong>Image title</strong><span>label</span></div>
                <div class="masonry-image"><img src="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5591/15041649519_f9862e81c9_z.jpg" rel="noindex" class="cover" width="360" height="240" alt=""></div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="" class="masonry-holder" title="">
                <div class="masonry-caption"><strong>Image title</strong><span>label</span></div>
                <div class="masonry-image"><img src="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5596/15228427075_a56b625397_z.jpg" rel="noindex" class="cover" width="360" height="240" alt=""></div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="" class="masonry-holder" title="">
                <div class="masonry-caption"><strong>Image title</strong><span>label</span></div>
                <div class="masonry-image"><img src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3917/15228055382_58c02657b8_z.jpg" rel="noindex" class="cover" width="360" height="240" alt=""></div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="" class="masonry-holder" title="">
                <div class="masonry-caption"><strong>Image title</strong><span>label</span></div>
                <div class="masonry-image"><img src="https://farm6.staticflickr.com/5553/15228056972_9b780d2891_z.jpg" rel="noindex" class="cover" width="360" height="240" alt=""></div>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
<!-- masonry ends -->
```

Here's a responsive masonry grid made with flexbox, if someone else need a bit inspiration for their work.

Answer (score 0):

Use bootstrap Grid System

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="pink">

        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
          <div class="lightblue">

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
          <div class="lightblue">

          </div>
        </div>
    <div class="clearfix">

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
       <div class="gray">

      </div>

    </div>

      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
          <div class="lightblue">

          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
          <div class="lightblue">

          </div>
        </div>
    <div class="clearfix">

    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
       <div class="gray">

      </div>

    </div>

      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
        <div class="pink">

        </div>
      </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

In CSS

```
.pink
{
  background-color:#FFB5FB;
  height:230px;
}
.lightblue
{
  background-color:#C6F4FE;
  height:100px;
}
.gray
{
  background-color:#B3EDAD;
  height:100px;
  margin:30px 0px;

}
.col, .col-1, .col-10, .col-11, .col-12, .col-2, .col-3, .col-4, .col-5, .col-6, .col-7, .col-8, .col-9, .col-auto, .col-lg, .col-lg-1, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-auto, .col-md, .col-md-1, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-auto, .col-sm, .col-sm-1, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-auto, .col-xl, .col-xl-1, .col-xl-10, .col-xl-11, .col-xl-12, .col-xl-2, .col-xl-3, .col-xl-4, .col-xl-5, .col-xl-6, .col-xl-7, .col-xl-8, .col-xl-9, .col-xl-auto
{
  padding-right: 3px;
    padding-left: 3px;
}
```

Here is the demo on Jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/d3aht26z/11/

Comment: Is that really the way the op asked for?

Comment: Bootstrap is great as a grid framework to structure the skeleton of your website, but sadly not for this purpose.